# Receipt printing in roll paper

Tags: c#, unicode, printing, drawstring

I searched for a lot in google and did not find what i actually wanted. I got following code, which will print the variable `name`. I got a Epson Dot Matrix Printer and Roll Paper (Endless continuous paper).

My problem is that, after printing `name` paper feeds up to size of `A4`. I don`t want the paper feed. This application is intended to do print receipts which will have unlimited data which need to be printed flawless ( with out page break).

Can you, the smart folk out there to point me in the correct direction with these codes?
**edited this code and changed scenario .. please move down further**

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  Font Heading2 = new Font("Times New Roman", 13);
  StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
  sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
  sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
  //e.HasMorePages = false;
  PaperSize pkCustomSize1 = new PaperSize("First custom size", 100, 200);
  pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pkCustomSize1;
  e.Graphics.DrawString(name.ToString(), Heading1, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width / 2), e.MarginBounds.Top, sf);
}
```

**Edit 1:-** @Adriano Repetti suggested this is a duplicate with [Form feed in c# printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608938/form-feed-in-c-sharp-printing). What i learned from the above question is that he want to **add the form feed**. But i want to **remove the form feed**.

**Edit 2:-** I got an another hint by googling that **setting the `page Height` equal to `line height`** will make stop feeding which sounds promising. I am trying to figure that out too.

**Edit 3:-** @Adriano Repetti suggested me with Raw Printing (Directly printing binary data) with [KB link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322090). I googled around about it, and found out its c# **better** equivalent [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/8CJFmU8h) or  [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/10231151) (provided because it is a handy one) . At first it sounded good and it worked nicely stopping form feeding. But eventually i struck some ice berg.

- On my code i had to align some printing quotes to **center** or align to **left**`. for which i got only option of using **space** and **tabs**. But there will be no guaranty that it will be well formatted as we can not certain about built in fonts with printer.( [Refer:SO Question by @syncis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454629/string-formatting-and-printing) )
- And secondly, i will have to move my application to **unicode(local language support)** capable one, at least with in a month or so. In that scenario, raw printing wont help and i will have to go through theses faces again. SO, For avoiding that its better for me to stay with **Graphics DrawString**. And for this i changed my code as.

//---------
    //  start button click
    //---------    
    PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
    pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 300;
    pdoc.Print();
    //---------
    //  end button click
    //---------

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  Font Heading2 = new Font("Times New Roman", 13);

  // changed following statement to met with new **unicode** criteria
  //e.Graphics.DrawString(name.ToString(), Heading1, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width / 2), e.MarginBounds.Top, sf);

 TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "My name in local language is വിനീത്", Heading2, new Point(0, 0), Color.Black);
}
```

With current problems, i am redefining the Question extending tag to **unicode** as.

**How can print with** `TextRenderer.DrawText with unicode support` `without form feeding` **?**  I think setting paper height to line height will solve my problem. If so how or suggest me a better way to stop paper feeding. It really eats a lot of my valuable time...

**EDIT 4:** Today I found out a very interesting thing about my printer. I cant even set custom paper size manually (Not by coding.. I mean control panel->printers and faxes ->Epson LX-300+ ->properties -> printing preference-> paper/quality -> advanced -> paper size -> BOOOOOM not showing my custom paper size). I am using Epson LX-300+ printer. Do guys think it wont support custom paper sizes? is that causing me problems?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I don`t think it is duplicate. Because in [Form feed in c# printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608938/form-feed-in-c-sharp-printing) trying insert form feed and here i am trying to remove the form field.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted wrong link. AFAIK problem is that PrintDocument will add a form-feed for each page and all it's logic assume you're printing a page each time. Yes you may keep data until a page is completed or do it in the right (hard) way as described in this article (for VB.NET but code is pretty easy to translate): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322090

Comment: Thank you @Adriano Repetti for [KB link](support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322090). I run the code in separate VB Project and it executed as if it was made for me. I will be converting the code shortly and will post updates on it.

Comment: Using the PrintDocument class is just the wrong approach.  Printing in Windows is page-based, as long as you use the printer driver you will always get the formfeed.  It is also notoriously slow, too slow for point-of-sale apps.  You need to bypass the driver and send the commands to the printer directly, [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091) shows how.  Multiply the "eating time" problem by at least a factor of pi squared.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I know it has performance problem. I don`t  have any other option. I already explained it with EDIT 3. When printing i need Unicode support and a way to format print string.

Comment: Can you give some code that use rawPrinterHelp with unicode support

Comment: @Hans Passant, I already tried  `StreamPrinter class` that you posted in MSDN forum.

Comment: I wonder why the form feed you get feeds to a A4 size?? If you set a page size correctly it always hould feed to the currently set pagesize and in doing so not create a problem. Do you have an idea why it assumes that A4 is the papersize? did you query the printer dirver about the pagesizes it supports?

Comment: I dont have any idea about that!!

Comment: I cant even set custom paper size manually (Not by coding.. I mean control panel->printers and faxes ->Epson LX-300+ ->properties -> printing preference-> paper/quality -> advanced -> paper size -> BOOOOOM not showing my custom paper size). I am using Epson LX-300+ printer. Do guys think it wont support custom paper sizes? is that causing me problems?

Comment: i think i figured out the problem. `Epson LX-300 driver` not  supporting paper size customization. so i changed the default driver to `Epson FX-100+ driver` and suddenly my code started working as i expected. I'll keep you posted, you guys...

Comment: That's exactly what I would have suggested (changing printer drivers), although not with huge expectations.. Glad you are making progress.. You may want to post the working code, maybe with the query to find the supported sizes as an answer..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by my self ( sorry for my english ) As Hans Passant says ( PrintDocument is page based. end of story ) You must use ( e.HasMorePages = true; )

---

```
float cordenadaX;
float cordenadaY;

int totalPages;
int paginaAtual;
int indiceItem;
List<string> items;
public void ImprimeDanfeNFCe()
{
    totalPages = 1;
    paginaAtual = 1;
    indiceItem = 0;
    cordenadaX = 0;
    cordenadaY = 0;

    items = new List<string>();
    items.Add("Item1");
    items.Add("Item2");
    items.Add("Item3");
    (............)

    PrintDocument recordDoc = new PrintDocument();

    recordDoc.DocumentName = "xMarket danfe";

    recordDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(imprimeDanfeReceipt);
    PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
    ps.PrinterName = "My printer";
    recordDoc.PrinterSettings = ps;
    recordDoc.Print();
    recordDoc.Dispose();
}
void imprimeDanfeReceipt(PrintPageEventArgs e)    
{
   float pageHeight = e.MarginBounds.Height;

   string text = "";
   if (paginaAtual == 1)
   {
      text = "Cupom header";
      e.Graphics.DrawString(text, drawFontDanfeTitulo, drawBrush, new 
           RectangleF(cordenadaX, cordenadaY, width, height), 
           drawFormatCenter);
      cordenadaY += e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, drawFontDanfeTitulo).Height;
   }
   for (int i = indiceItem; i < items.Count; i++)
   {
       int indice = i + 1;
       //items[i] Is very important to not print same items again while print next page
       e.Graphics.DrawString(items[i], drawFontDanfeItems, drawBrush, 
           new RectangleF(cordenadaX, cordenadaY, width, height), drawFormatLeft);
       cordenadaY += e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, drawFontDanfeTitulo).Height;
       indiceItem++;
       //cordenadaY+100 is for the size of the footer
       if (cordenadaY+100 >= pageHeight)
       {
           paginaAtual++;
           e.HasMorePages = true;
           return;
       }
    }
   e.Graphics.DrawString("page footer", drawFontDanfeItems, drawBrush, 
       new RectangleF(cordenadaX, cordenadaY, width, height), drawFormatLeft);
   cordenadaY += e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, drawFontDanfeTitulo).Height;
```

}